# Effect of changing page protection inside the code section of a DLL?

Tags: windows, dll

I want to change the protection for the memory pages of a hole function inside a Dll to be no more executable.

Does this affect other processes which mapped the same dll into virtual address space?

Comment: I'm curious if you can get the "end address" / size of the function.

Comment: hm thats actually a good question. Maybe I took the start address of the next function to calculate the size. I looked in IDA and it seems there is 4 Byte of NOPs after a function and then comes the next function. So I can calculate the size of a function if it is not the last function inside the dll. I looked at the ntdll. Dont know if this is always the case.

Comment: Imagine if this were true. You could DoS the entire operating system by writing a program that looks for ntdll.dll and changes the protection to non-executable.

Comment: AFAIK, memory page protection / NX bits / DEP works on virtual memory (mapping), not physical memory. Therefore, processes with unrelated virtual memory mappings (i.e. other processes) are not affected. How do you want to change the "protection for the memory pages"?

Comment: I want to change the protection via VirtualProtect(). But I dont know if there are better ones for my problem. According to MSDN VirtualProtect "Changes the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space of the calling process". So if it works on virtual memory it does not affect other processes?

Comment: I think the os can not manage privileges for every byte, the privileges is for a whole chunck of memory, and if you change that chunck, other functions inside will also be disabled. I don't think it'll affect other processes. But it may throw an error and exit.

Comment: Damn you are right, since there is only 4 Byte between two functions there might be pages (4 KB) where more then one function resides in. Too bad :(

Comment: It says it right there in the documentation you quoted. "Changes the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space *of the calling process*." It explicitly says that it affects the calling process, not all processes.

Comment: @user2252343 There is no requirement that the code for a function be contiguous. PGO can break functions up into pieces. Also, why are you messing with page protection of code in the first place? This is generally not recommended engineering practice and will probably be very fragile and unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, it doesn't.**

The NX bit works at the virtual/page level. Each process has their own virtual address space, and cannot directly affect another process' address space (barring shared memory).

Different processes can share mapped pages of a DLL. If one process alters a page, copy-on-write kicks in and that process gets a unique copy of the page, the other processes' view(s) of the DLL are unaffected.

For more information on NX, see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html) (Volume 3A linked, 7 volumes total).

Also, here is an older but still relevant Microsoft [article on copy-on-write protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103858).